# Reducing hard disk access of kvm

Tags: linux-kvm, qemu

I have set up a kvm/qemu virtual machine on my home server (Ubuntu Server 12.04). My host system is installed on a small SSD but the image for the vm (virtual disk file) is saved on a classic HDD. Since I run that vm the HDD doesn't seem to stop spinning and I can also hear the heads jumping every few seconds. Is there a way to reduce this access? My guest system is also an Ubuntu Server 12.04 with swap disabled. It has 1536 MB current allocation and 2048 maximum allocation. Host has 4GB RAM.

Here is the `/etc/fstab` of the guest system (without the default comment block):

```
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/integration-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=1cea0a98-2d6b-4338-b33c-f3aa76819c35 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
```

Comment: Which system has swap disabled? How much memory is available to the host and the guest? Is the guest run directly from a block device or a virtual disk file? How are partitions mounted in the guest? Could you check if there are files changing in the guest file system with something like `find / -cmin -60`?

Comment: @Eroen edited my question according to your questions. `find / -cmin -60` returns a lot of files. Not sure but it may be all of the files there are.

Comment: @Eroen forgot to ask: What does `find / -cmin -60` do exactly? I haven't worked with `find` a lot.

Comment: It finds files that were modified less than 60 minutes ago. You could try `sudo find / -xdev -cmin -5` or so at least 5 minutes after booting? `-xdev` makes it not descend into `/proc` and `/sys` &c.

Comment: OK, I will do it again when I am sure that nothing was used intendedly.

Comment: I've now tried `sudo find / -xdev -cmin -1` because the access is pretty frequent. I found out that my jenkins writes a lot into temp although it is idle. I've now shutdown jenkins and will observe how the HDD activity changes.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Although I'm not sure if the HDD is spinning down the heads definitely stopped moving all the time. The disk access on the guest system checks out now so I guess the spindown problem is on the hosts side (maybe still related to kvm?). Also I have to find out how to reduce jenkins disk access but that doesn't belong to this question.

Comment: @Eroen if you post the trick with `find` for finding out what uses the disk as answer I'll give you some karma. Still got to look into the spindown problem but if that one turns out to have nothing to do with kvm I'll also mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: The problem kind of solved itself because the SSD crashed. I now bought a bigger one so that my images would fit on it instead of the HDD.

Answer (score 1):

The VM will map disk access to disk access and RAM access to RAM access. That means that Ubuntu swapping to disk causes real disk access, which you can avoid by giving Ubuntu more VM memory.

Comment: Does Ubuntu swap if swap is disabled?

Comment: It still pages out code. That's backed by executables after all, not swap. Since it can't page out old data pages, it may choose be forced to page out newer code pages. I.e. you might be inducing Ubuntu to make worse choices by running without swap.

Comment: OK, I checked RAM usage with `top` and it was a little to close to the limit. For testing purposes I gave the vm more RAM and the disk accesses seem to be a little less than before but its still to often. I will upgrade my host memory anyway (to be able to give the guest more permanently) because this seems to be at least part of the problem. Thanks! :-)